# How to pass variable using post method?

Tags: php

There are a page page1.php below:-

```
<?php
    $name = "xyz";
?>
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    Age : <input type="number" name="age">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

after submitting the form at page1,
How to get value of $name of page1.php in page2.php
what should change in page-1?

Comment: Add this to your form <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask also for a name on page1, then simply use another input:

```php
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name">
    Age : <input type="number" name="age">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

If the name is fixed and you want it transmitted via POST, usa a hidden input:

```php
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    Name : <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>">
    Age : <input type="number" name="age">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Then in page2.php read the POST-ed value:

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the parameters in page1 by setting the hidden mode in the form，like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field＿name" value=$name >
```

You can get it in Page2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input type.

Just be aware that users can edit these values so you should consider any vulnerability this may bring.